# What is differences between arguments and inputs?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am in trouble with `xargs` and `pipe` commands. Here is one example =

```
echo 'a' | xargs mkdir
```

This command creates a directory which name is `a`. So I can understand that this commmand is equivalent to `mkdir a`

But why doesn't this command work = `echo 'a' | mkdir` ?

I read that `pipe` command transfer left command's output as a input to right one , when `| xargs` command transfers left command's output as a argument to right one.

**1-What are differences between input and argument  ?**

**2-`echo 'a' | mkdir` why doesn't this command work and what is equivalent of this command ?**

Thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Simple answer

The arguments are an input.

## Longer answer

There are also other types of input.

In your example `echo 'a' | mkdir` you are expecting `mkdir` to read its standard input. However `mkdir` is not written to do this.

What you are calling input is standard-input (`stdin`). And output is standard-out (`stdout`). There is all standard-error (`stderr`). And an exit code.

## Even longer answer -- so what is the difference?

The arguments must be available before the program is started. It is typically: short; contains options, filenames, and short text.

Standard-in can be written to as the program is running; data can be sent to it, that did not exist when the program was started; It is not guaranteed that you can read it out of order (so read it sequentially); It can be of arbitrary length; There is only one standard-in per process, if you need more send file-names as arguments;

### How to do `echo 'a' | xargs mkdir` without `xargs`

```
mkdir "$(echo 'a')"
```

The `$()` means run the contained command, then replace the `$()` and its content with the standard-out of that command.

Answer (score 0):

I was confused about this too, for a very long time. I'll take a slightly may be simpler example (I am by far no bash expert):

```
wc "test" 
wc <<< "test" (same as: echo "test" | wc)
```

The result of these two are very different. The first one tries to read a file `test`, the second one shows `1 1 5`.

The issue here is that `wc "test"` gets the *argument* `"test"` as input, while `wc <<< "test"` takes *stdin*.

---

So when you issue `echo 'a' | xargs mkdir` (xargs stands for: execute as an argument), you are passing an *argument* to `mkdir`; it's like doing: `mkdir a`.

On the other hand, when you issue `echo 'a' | mkdir` (simpler would be : `mkdir <<< 'a'`), you pass `a` as stdin.

`mkdir` treats these things very differently, thus the result you see.